# Speech Recognition on OSX

Tags: macos, speech-recognition

How can I use OSX's speech-to-text tools programmatically?  OSX has offline "enhanced dictation" which essentially means that somewhere on my computer is all the data required to turn audio into speech.  I would like to invoke these capabilities from an executable.

I have seen some AppleScript files essentially do this, but I can't get them to work on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSSpeechRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004113) is an API that provides access to the older "Speakable Items" functionality that's been around since before OS X (now called "Dictation Commands", and requiring Enhanced Dictation).

This is just a command interface, though — that is, you provide a list of commands, and it tells you when the user has spoken one of them. There's no public API for full speech-to-text dictation.